# Android SQLite SELECT syntax error apex

Tags: android, sqlite, select

I created this parametric query that works perfectly. Now when a string is passed with an apex, I get this error

```
SQLiteException: near "'%'":
```

thi is the query

```
String sql = "SELECT titolo, icona, colore, tipo, identificativo, dato_campo FROM table " +
            "WHERE titolo LIKE '%" + parametro + "%' " +
            "OR dato_campo LIKE '%" + parametro + "%' GROUP BY identificativo";
```

if `parametro` It is a string of this type `stringa'`, i get the error.

How can I fix?

Comment: please add your complete crash log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is that your String has a single quote characters which breaks your SQL Query String.

Simulating `parametro == test01` - **OK**

```
"SELECT titolo, icona, colore, tipo, identificativo, dato_campo FROM table WHERE titolo LIKE '%test01%' OR dato_campo LIKE '%test01%' GROUP BY identificativo";
```

Simulating `parametro == stringa'` **NOK**

```
"SELECT titolo, icona, colore, tipo, identificativo, dato_campo FROM table WHERE titolo LIKE '%stringa'%' OR dato_campo LIKE '%stringa'%' GROUP BY identificativo";
```

As you can see, your string is producing `'%stringa'%'` which is invalid for a SQL query.

You should escape that character `'` during your query to something like: `%stringa''%'`.

So, you can add something as follows before creating your Query String:

```
parametro = parametro.replaceAll("\'","''");
String sql = "SELECT titolo, icona, colore, tipo, identificativo, dato_campo FROM table " +
        "WHERE titolo LIKE '%" + parametro + "%' " +
        "OR dato_campo LIKE '%" + parametro + "%' GROUP BY identificativo";
```

This is a support about the issue that your are facing now... As Gabe Sechan mentioned on the other answer, raw queries should be discouraged.

**UPDATE**

Safe way to run your query is:

```
String paramentro = "stringa'";
Cursor cursor = db.query("tablename", new String [] {"titolo", "icona", "colore", "tipo", "identificativo", "dato_campo"}, "titolo LIKE ? OR dato_campo LIKE ?", new String[]{"%"+paramentro+"%", "%"+paramentro+"%"}, "identificativo", null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't write SQL queries like this using concatenation.  It leaves you wide open to SQL injection attacks.  Instead, use bound parameters.  Not only will this make your queries more efficient, they prevent SQL injection.